# Java/eclipse: Why can't I run a prog with package by Run Configuration? Pic inside

Tags: java, eclipse

Someone help me please? I don't know why can't I run a simple program by the run configuration. If I don't set a package in the beginning it works.
[image]
I attach a picture of my screen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class `bb` is in the package `aa2`. Its name is thus `aa2.bb`, not `bb`.

Answer (score 0):

If not specified the package name externally then a given class is said to be included in default package i.e this class exists directly under **src** folder.

If you remove the **package** statement in the class then you have to move this class to one folder level up, in order to run this class.

But it is discouraged and normally it is expected that each class should declare its own package statement.